# error with fetching tweets after refresh

Tags: php, twitter

First of all i want to apologize if this is the most basic question ever! I'm not that good with php but i'm learning.

I can't find a solution or even understand why it's going wrong all the time. I do want to know *why* this is happening

I'm trying to get the two latest tweets from a twitter account. I don't want to use massive (existing, i know) classes or codes which i don't understand. So i tried the following myself:

```
 $timeline = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=Mau_ries";
    $data = file_get_contents($timeline);
    $tweets = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($tweets as $tweet){
        echo($tweet->text." - ".$tweet->created_at);
        if (++$i == 2) break;
    }
```

When i first ran this code i got the text from my tweets, but when i refreshed the page i *sometimes* get the following error:

> **Warning:** file_get_contents(http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=Mau_ries) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in **/path/to/file** on line 88
>
> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /public/sites/www.singledays.nl/tmp/index.php:89 Stack trace: #0 /public/sites/www.singledays.nl/tmp/index.php(89): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in **/path/to/file** on line 89

Lines 88 & 89 are these:

```
$data = file_get_contents($timeline);
$tweets = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

Really weird. Sometimes it work, sometimes not.

Does anybody know this issue and/or a solution? And why does the error seem to occur randomly (Allthough it;s now erroring for a while allready)?

Thanks!

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What does `$data` contain when the call fails? It's not valid XML - it's probably an error message from Twitter because either the service is not reachable, or you hit some rate limit on Twitter's end.

Comment: PHP says it can't parse the xml. Catch the exception and dump the xml so you can review it with a naked eye.

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the limits of using the twitter api. Check https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following

Comment: Hmm.. i maybe loaded the xml 20 times. Would be a bit weird (in my eyes) if that's the max. Because now it works again. Is it maybe the time between page refreshes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$timeline = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=Mau_ries";
$data = @file_get_contents($timeline);

if($data){
    $fh = fopen("cache/".sha1($timeline),"w");
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}else{
    $fh = @fopen("cache/".sha1($timeline),"r");
    $data = "";
    while(!feof($fh)){ $data = fread($fh, 1024); }
    fclose($fh);
}

if(!$data) die("could not open url or find a cache of url locally");

$tweets = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

$i = 0;
foreach($tweets as $tweet){
    echo($tweet->text." - ".$tweet->created_at);
    if (++$i == 2) break;
}
```

There as every one has said debugging you should really cache the results in files and if it fails to download then use the cache the above code will do it for you.